# Heartbeat connection between Node.js and Python Flask with sockets? Possible?

Tags: python, flask

I am facing a situation where I have an Express server and a Flask server, each responsible for various tasks. We are piping a request from Express through to the Flask server, and would like to use sockets to provide heartbeat style updates from the Flask server to the Express server.

Is it possible to use sockets like this? I admit to having never really used sockets for backend stuff before. I've used Socket.io to connect React-based sites with an Express backend, but I'm not sure how to connect two servers like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Flask extension for Socket.io](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Even though the blurb text says "Flask-SocketIO gives Flask applications access to low latency bi-directional communications between the clients and the server", "clients" doesn't have to mean "frontend".

Since you've already used Socket.io and websockets, you might see if that package meets your need. Certainly easier than reaching immediately for Unix sockets if it turns out you don't have to. :)

Many WSGI servers only handle more one request at a time per worker. Flask-SocketIO uses async workers, so this should not be a bottleneck.

[Automatic threading with Flask](https://medium.com/@dkhd/handling-multiple-requests-on-flask-60208eacc154)

[WSGI is synchronous](http://www.475cumulus.com/single-post/2017/04/03/WSGI-Is-Not-Enough-Anymore)